# porting synproxy to user space

Tags: c, kernel, netfilter

I have ported the kernel's synproxy code to user space. I use it as a transparent proxy between the client and the web server.
When I request a web page, it works fine (the web page is below 512kbit). However, if I access a huge file (4Gbit or more), it will not continue to transfer after 3Gbits is transmitted.

I have adjusted the "confirmation" sent by the server to the client and the "seq" sent from the client to the server. At the same time, the tcp option "sack" sent from the client to the server is also adjusted.

```
 if(tcpinp->state == CONNTRACK_SYN_SENT){              
    if(tcphdr->tcp_flags == (TCP_SYN_FLAG|TCP_ACK_FLAG)){ 
        synproxy_parse_options(tcphdr, &opts);            
        tcpinp->tsoff = opts.tsval - tcpinp->its;         
    }                                                     

    swap(opts.tsval, opts.tsecr);                         
    synproxy_send_server_ack(iphdr,tcphdr, &opts);      
    /* send client ack,update tcp window */               
    swap(opts.tsval, opts.tsecr);      
 /*                                          
  * update window to client                  
  *                                          
  * dir:server -> client   
  *                           
  * save isn_off =  client.ISN1 - server.ISN2   
  */                                                                                                           
    tcpinp->isn_off = tcpinp->isn - tcphdr->seq;                
    synproxy_send_client_ack(tcpinp, &opts);     
    tcpinp->state = CONNTRACK_ESTABLISHED;            
    return 0;                                             
}                                                         

   if(tcpinp->dir == IP_CT_DIR_REPLY){                                      
       tcphdr->sent_seq = htonl(ntohl(tcphdr->sent_seq) + tcpinp->isn_off);                                
   }else if(tcpinp->dir == IP_CT_DIR_ORIGINAL){                             
       tcphdr->recv_ack = htonl(ntohl(tcphdr->recv_ack) - tcpinp->isn_off); 
       nf_ct_sack_adjust(tcph, other_way);                
   }
```

What should I adjust besides seq / ack and sack?

Comment: First, I must applaud you for porting kernel code to userspace. That's often a difficult task to partake in.

Comment: I found that the client tcp'win' option has been increased to '828800' and then it does not change.
What should i do next? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

---I found that the client tcp'win' option has been increased to '828800' and then it does not change.

I have solved ,that it need 'mss' is always same.